# Ajax request cannot access method on .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I'm trying to call a method in my .aspx file to call another .aspx file. The file that I am using is inside another folder, and the file I need to access using javascript is outside similar to this structure:

> Root Folder: 
>  PageMethods.aspx   
>    
>   SubFolder/  
>        Somefile.aspx

Here is my ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/PageMethods.aspx/TagtoVehicle",
        data: "{'colIDBigint': '" + IDBigInt + "', 'colTravelReqIDInt': " + TravelReq +
            ", 'colRecordLocatorVarchar': " + RecordLoc + ", 'colSeafarerIdInt': " + SeafarerId + ", 'colOnOff': " + onoff + ", 'colPortAgentVendorIDInt': " + Vehiclevendor + ", 'UserId': " + userId + "}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        } ,
        error: function(objXMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

When I run the ajax request it throws an error 500 (Internal Server Error).

Why is the request not going thru, even if inside my PageMethod.aspx.cs is this:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string TagtoVehicle(Int32 colIDBigint, Int32 colTravelReqIDInt, string colRecordLocatorVarchar, Int32 colSeafarerIdInt, string colOnOff, Int32 colPortAgentVendorIDInt,string UserId)
        {

}
```

What is triggering the error 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missign quotes around values.Just like you have encoded value of colIDBigint do same for all of the remaning

```
data: "{'colIDBigint': '" + IDBigInt + "', 'colTravelReqIDInt': '" + TravelReq +
        "', 'colRecordLocatorVarchar': '" + RecordLoc + "', 'colSeafarerIdInt': '" + SeafarerId + "', 'colOnOff': '" + onoff + "', 'colPortAgentVendorIDInt': '" + Vehiclevendor + "', 'UserId': '" + userId + "'}",
```

Better is that you stringify the data like this

```
JSON.stringify({colIDBigint:IDBigInt,colTravelReqIDInt:TravelReq})
```

and like that add other values in data.

Answer (score 0):

Use full url:

```
url: '<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/PageMethods.aspx/TagtoVehicle")%>',
```

~ means that the path will start at the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Error: 500 cause by your data format: make it simply, try this:

```
data:{"variable":data, "variable1":data1,...}
```

Jquery latest version support this kind, you can give a try! As my experience, this way is better. Good luck